# How to perform custom auth validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a laravel application by using custom auth. By whych, user can login using mobile number alone. And once they enter mobile number and submit they will recieve one time password on mobile as sms. And on the next screen they should enter the one time password and login in. And i have successfully implemented this funcitons.

But my problem is when i validate one time password, if its correct it log's in and if its wrong i get a error stating **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**, I dont know which causes this error, as all the routes are in POST only.

Please guide me to achive this, if the one time password is wrong the page should redirect to same page stating the error showing "One time password is not matched".

My Route:

```
Auth::routes(['login' => false]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/otp', 'AuthController@showOtpForm')->name('otp');

Route::post('/loginsuccess', 'AuthController@loginsuccess')->name('loginsuccess');
```

And form tag on Login.blade.php is as follows

```
<form class="login-form" action="{{ route('otp') }}" method="post">
```

And form tag and hidden value from login page on otp.blade.php is as follows

```
<form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('loginsuccess') }}">

<input type="hidden" value="{{ $phone }}" name="phone">
```

And my Auth Controller is as follows,

```
 public function showOtpForm(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $newotp =  mt_rand(100000, 999999);

            $user = User::where('phone', $request->phone)->firstOrFail();
            $user->otp = $newotp;
            $user->save();

            return view('auth.otp')->with('phone', $request->phone);
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            //dd(get_class_methods($e)); // lists all available methods for exception object
            echo "No user found, please register or try again later.";
        }

    }


    public function loginsuccess(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $user = User::where('phone', $request->phone)->firstOrFail();
                if($user->otp === $request->otp)
                {
                    Auth::login($user);
                    return redirect()->route('home');
                }else{
                    return redirect()->back();
                }
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            dd($e);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to validate, if one time password is correct means it should go to route ('home') and if one time password is wrong then it should be redirect to same page on which users types one time password but with error.

Comment: On which page is the login form?

Comment: which route you got this error?

Comment: default login route of laravel contains login form

Comment: getting error on otp route when i give wrong one time password @BhargavChudasama

Comment: The login form is on `/login`?

Comment: yes correct @thmspl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following statement:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

This redirects the user back on your `otp` route. You defined that the route is only accessible by using a `POST` request. The problem is that the redirection uses a `GET` request.

So either you think about redirecting the user to the `login` route like `return redirect()->route('login');` so that he has to enter his mobile number again (would eventually be a little bit more secure) or you change your `otp` route from `GET` to `POST` like this:

```
Route::get('/otp', 'AuthController@showOtpForm')->name('otp');
```

If you change `POST` to `GET` you must also change the method in your form on the login view.

---

BTW: You can not pass `login => false` as parameter for `Auth::routes()`. Possible parameters are:

```
Auth::routes([
  'register' => false, // Registration Routes...
  'reset' => false, // Password Reset Routes...
  'verify' => false, // Email Verification Routes...
]);
```

You need to override the login route and just redirect it to home or somewhere else.

Comment: It works if i uses ```return redirect()->route('login');``` but i need to redirect to route('otp') with error saying wrong one time password

Comment: There's the problem. The route `otp` is for post requests only. What is the difference between the `login` and the `otp` route?

Comment: login contains input field for mobile number and otp contains input for one time password which will be recieved on users mobile when they press submit on login page,

Comment: It works, but it shows all information on search bar including csrf token, any way to resolve this ?

Comment: All informations are in the url if you use a `GET` request. You can't change this. I would suggest to simply redirect the user back to the `login` page and let them entry the mobile number again. Other similar websites have the same logic. Its more secure than let the user directly enter a new OTP token.

Comment: On pressing login button on login page, it hits showOtpForm function on controller, and uses phone from requests to find the record on table, then it generates otp and then it goes to otp page. In this page user will enter otp which they get on mobile. If its validates then it logins else it should error , this is the whole logic

Comment: Ya may be, but other websites give users to re enter the otp if the verification failed.

Comment: Just simply redirect the users to the `login` page. Specially if you don't have any idea what the differences between a `GET` and a `POST` request are.